# Thymeleaf TemplateEngine unable to process templates on remote server

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jakarta-mail

I am attempting to send emails using Thymeleaf from a SpringBoot application. Templates are processed locally using the following method:

```
public String build(MailType mailType, Map<String, Object> messageMap) {

    Context context = new Context();

    context.setVariables(messageMap);
    return templateEngine.process("/mail/" + mailType.name(), context);

}
```

MailType is an Enum with the names of each template stored, for example NEWUSER. Mail templates are stored in src/main/resources/templates/mail/

This sends an email as intended when running locally, but when running on the server, I receive the following error message:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/mail/NEWUSER], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard-coding the plain text /mail/ was the problem. Used a TemplateResolver and this fixed the issue.

```
context.setVariables(messageMap);

    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();

    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/mail/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(0);

    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
```

(May not be best practice, any better ideas?)

Comment: I am going to mark this as an answer, but please notify me if there's a better way to do this and I'll accept that answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do the same that @matgr wrote but do not forget to pass an empty string to templateEngine.proccess method like below.

```
return templateEngine.process("", context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provide suffix in above case.Don't you have html pages in static directory for processing.
Please show the html page that you want to use for email that might be you have put in /mail/ directory.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: Hi Vishal, 5th line down is where I provide the suffix, I was going to delete this question and its answer as I believe there are better answers elsewhere, but I have kept it as Stack discouraged me from deleting it (as I technically found a solution).

To answer your other questions, the HTML file is irrelevant (and slightly sensitive), as it's a valid template so I didn't provide it. I do store HTML pages in a static directory, i.e. src/main/resources/templates, however I created a /mail subdirectory in order to keep things tidier. Apologies for the confusion.